# JQuery sortable function return empty string

Tags: asp.net-core, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, razor-pages

Here this sortable function is return emplty string

> Index.cshtml

```
<div id="sortable" class="col-lg-9 col-md-9">
    @foreach (var chart in Model.Charts)
    {
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 hidden" id=@string.Format("chartNumber{0}", chart.ChartOrder)>
            <figure class="highcharts-figure1">
                <div id=@string.Format("container{0}", chart.ChartOrder)></div>
            </figure>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$("#sortable").sortable({
    containment: 'parent',
    cursor: 'move',
    scroll: false,
    update: function () {
        var order = $("#sortable").sortable('serialize');
        console.log(order); // emplty string
    }
});
```

I want that when user update the charts order then new array should be formed so that i can send this array to the Post function so that i can store the sequence of the charts.
But here this sortable function is return empty string, so need help

Comment: Hi @MalikHaseeb, any updates about this case? Do you try the approach that I shared?

Comment: Yes your answer solved my problem thank you @FeiHan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want that when user update the charts order then new array should be formed so that I can send this array to the Post function so that I can store the sequence of the charts.

In [API documentation of Sortable plugin](https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-serialize), we can find:

*It works by default by looking at the id of each item in the format "**setname_number**", and it spits out a hash like "setname[]=number&setname[]=number".*

So to achieve your requirement, please modify the code like below.

*Set `Id` of item as `setname_number`*

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6" id=@string.Format("setname_{0}", chart.ChartOrder)>
```

*Get new item order*

```
update: function () {

    //specify `key` based on your actual requirement
    var order = $("#sortable").sortable("serialize", { key: "sort" });
    console.log(order); 
}
```

Test Result

[image]